# Is it possible to procedurally render a mesh by generating a cloud of 3D RGB points?

Tags: point-clouds

I want to render monsters by procedurally generating a cloud of 3D RGB points representing their bodies. In other words, I want to be able to create a function:

```
def gen_3d_points():
  points = []
  ... arbitrary code ...
  return points
```

That will return all points to be rendered. Is this possible in Blender? How?

Answer (score 0):

Make a mesh that is a bunch of loose verts as a master object.
Make a small sphere and make it a child of that master object.
On that master object enable Dupliverts (2.7)/Instancing on verts (2.8).